# Eject button on internal drive

Tags: hard-drive, eject

Why is there an eject button on my internal 4tB hard drive? For an internal drive connected by sata, wouldn't you want to unmount the drive but leave it powered and only power it off when the computer turns off? What purpose does the eject option serve?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu. Consider asking on [su].

Comment: Funny but I know an answer for Marcel, please let me do it...

Comment: @Marcel - hello dont worry about buttons and some question can happen like it happened to us too, but you can explore a bit more, you know how to mount a device in the terminal, so you can eject too in the terminal : simply type in terminal :man eject - ( for more help ).

Comment: SATA spec support hotplug, (hot swapping) but your controller card must implement it for it to work. So unless you have a RAID controller to support this, you probably can't just eject it. Also, a backplane really helps for ejecting an internal disk, it needs to eject, but also insert.  why hot swap? Cuz uptime is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of reasons to have an "eject" button on an internal hard disk:

- On laptops: to save power: if you have both an SSD and a HDD, you can turn off the (power hungry) HDD
- On servers: to remove the drive while keeping the rest of the server running
- On desktops: to power down a backup HDD prior to removing it
  ...